# Correct way of stubbing method call in RSpec request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stubbing

I am trying to stub out an :authenticate_user method call in my request spec so I can test the user's association creation. I am using these blog posts as a guide on stubbing:

1) https://8thlight.com/blog/mike-knepper/2014/07/01/stubbing-authentication-and-authorization-in-controller-specs.html

2) http://johnnyji.me/rspec/2015/06/18/stubbing-controller-instance-methods-in-rspec.html

I'm not having any success with stubbing and I can't figure out what am I missing.

When I tried

```
it 'creates a new contract' do
      allow(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user).and_return(user)
      post api_v1_user_contracts_path(user), { params: contract_params}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
```

I got:
[image]

When I tried:

```
it 'creates a new contract' do
      allow_any_instance_of(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user).and_return(user)
      post api_v1_user_contracts_path(user), { params: contract_params}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
```

I got [image]

My code:
spec/requests/contracts_api_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'pry'
context "POST #create" do
    let (:user) { User.create(full_name: "Jason Bourne", email: "jbourne@test.com", password: "123456") }
    let (:contract_params) do
      {
        "contract[vendor]" => "Lebara",
        "contract[starts_on]" => "2018-12-12",
        "contract[ends_on]" => "2018-12-16",
        "contract[price]" => "15"
      }
    end

    it 'creates a new contract' do
      allow(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user).and_return(user)

      post api_v1_user_contracts_path(user), { params: contract_params}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
```

app/controllers/api/v1/contracts_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ContractsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def show
    if @current_user.contracts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      render json: @current_user.contracts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      render json: { error: "Contract not found"}, status: 400
    end
  end

  def create
    contract = @current_user.contracts.build(contract_params)
    if contract.save
      render json: contract
    else
      render json: { error: contract.errors }, status: 400
    end
  end
```

app/controllers/concerns/token_authenticatable.rb

```
class NotAuthorizedException < StandardError; end

module TokenAuthenticatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_reader :current_user

    before_action :authenticate_user

    rescue_from NotAuthorizedException, with: -> { render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: :unauthorized }
  end

  private

  def authenticate_user
    @current_user = DecodeAuthenticationCommand.call(request.headers).result
    raise NotAuthorizedException unless @current_user
  end
end
```

Additional questions:

1) Should I be using a real User object, or should that be a double? I'm assuming it should be a real user in order to test if the association creation is working.

2) Should I be using allow(***Api::V1::ContractsController***).to receive(:authenticate_user).and_return(user)? I've tried it before and didn't work but I didn't know it was because something else also was breaking it.

Thanks for any feedback you can give!

Comment: I just tried and it works, thanks :). I guess I couldn't use a test double for the user or else there would be no point to this test?

Comment: I have moved my comment to the answer, it will be better for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that `authenticate_user` assigns user to the variable (and you use it later). Please try:

```
allow(DecodeAuthenticationCommand).to receive_message_chain(:call, :result).and_return(user)
```

With the test double, you will have to define all methods for the user, such as `contracts`. Also, you are checking if the contract was created - in my opinion, it is perfectly fine to use a real object for the `user`.

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure when it would've been appropriate to use a real object and you cleared it up.

Comment: Why wouldn't allow(Api::V1::ContractsController).to receive(:authenticate_user).and_return(user) or allow(controller).to .. work in this instance?

Comment: `authenticate_user` assigns `user` to `@current_user`. Later, in your code, you use `@current_user`. I think that your code will raise an error because `@current_user` will be nil (`contract = nil.contracts.build(contract_params)`)

Comment: Also `authenticate_user` doesn't actually return a `user`. When successful it will return `nil`.  So the `and_return` is misleading.

Comment: @Derek Sorry, I couldn't see why it wouldn't actually return a user if successful?

Comment: @MLZ the `authenticate_user` from your code assigns `user` to `@current_user` and returns `nil` or raises an exception. That's all.

Comment: RIght, that is because the result of the last statement is what is returned.